# Remote Installation support in InstallShield version 10

Tags: installshield

I have `InstallShiled` version 10, i am using it to create a `msi` (Microsoft installer).

1) I want to create a installer which can support remote installation.
2) I have done some googling but was not able to find any clue about the problem.

Is it possible to create a remote installer feature in `Installshield` version 10?

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield 10 doesn't exist.  There was an 'X' (Roman Numberal Ten) and a '2010' version.  Both supported Basic MSI projects which if done properly can be installed remotely.

Otherwise it's not clear what you are trying to do.